# How to find the coordinates of the farthest points of an ellipse from stat_ellipse in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this code that draws an ellipse using type `t`

```
df %>% 
  select(starts_with("WindSpeed"), starts_with("Humidity")) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  mutate(WindSpeed = (WindSpeed9am+WindSpeed3pm)/2,
         Humidity = (Humidity9am+Humidity3pm)/2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = WindSpeed, y = Humidity)) +
  geom_point(alpha = .4) +
  stat_ellipse(size = 2, color = "blue") + 
  geom_abline(intercept = 83, slope = -1.4, size = 2, color = "blue")
```

That yields this plot:

[image: Code_output]

I want to draw a line that goes through the points that are farthest on this ellipse.

How can i do this?

Edit: I tried to get the points from `car::car::dataEllipse` via this code segment

```
k <- df %>% 
  select(starts_with("WindSpeed"), starts_with("Humidity")) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  mutate(WindSpeed = (WindSpeed9am+WindSpeed3pm)/2,
         Humidity = (Humidity9am+Humidity3pm)/2) %>%
  select(WindSpeed, Humidity) %>%
  as.matrix() %>%
  car::dataEllipse(draw = F)

k <- k$`0.5` %>% data.frame()
distances <- dist(k)
max_distance_index <- which.max(distances)
distance_matrix <- as.matrix(distances)
row_index <- row(distance_matrix)[max_distance_index]
col_index <- col(distance_matrix)[max_distance_index]
farthest_points <- k[c(row_index, col_index), ]

a <- farthest_points[1,]
b <- farthest_points[2,]
m <- (b[2]-a[2])/(b[1]-a[1])
int <- a[2]-m*a[1]
```

But after adding a line to the ggplot with `m` and `intercept` this is the result.

[image: result2]

Comment: Could you please make the question reproducible by including the output of `dput(df)` in the question, or a smaller subset of `df` to enable the plot to be generated easily?

Comment: Since `stat_ellipse` doesn't return anything, I suggest you find some other tool to calculate the bounding ellipse.  Further, what you are **actually** asking for is the line that goes thru the two foci of the ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

If you go back and read `?stat_ellipse` you will see it's taken from `car::dataEllipse` which returns (invisibly) all the info you want about the ellipse that was created.